# ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC: IModelValidator object is not called at model binding, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, model-validation

I want to implement custom model validator. I have used example code from Pro ASP .NET Core MVC book and it is not working. The custom model validator method is never called, yet model validation is successful.

**Action method signature:**

```
[HttpPost] public IActionResult EditPerson(Person model, int id, **[ImageValidator]IFormFile file**)
```

The important object is the **file** parameter.

Inside the action method I use the following check, which evaluates always to true when the file parameter is there even if the validator should say that it its invalid (too big, wrong format atc..):

```
if (ModelState.GetValidationState(nameof(file)) == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid) {...}
```

The model validator looks this:

```
public class ImageValidatorAttribute : Attribute, IModelValidator {
    public bool IsRequired => true;

    // Max size of image in kilo Bytes
    public int MaxSize { get; set; } = 1024;
    // Allowed extensions
    public string Extensions { get; set; } = ".jpg .jpeg";

    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        **throw new NotImplementedException();**
        IFormFile file = context.Model as IFormFile;
        List<ModelValidationResult> result = new List<ModelValidationResult>();

        if (file != null) { 

            ......some code here....

        }
        return result;          
    }
}
```

My problem is, that execution never reaches the custom validator which is verified both by breakpoint and throw new Exception() line.

What am I missing?
Thanks for suggestions!
J

---

EDIT:
I have also tried with a ValidationAttribute object:

```
public class SizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int size;
    public SizeAttribute(int Size) => size = Size;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        IFormFile file = validationContext.ObjectInstance as IFormFile;
        if (size * 1024 < file.Length) return new ValidationResult($"A maximum image size of only {size}KB is allowed");
        else return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And here I have the action method

```
[HttpPost] public IActionResult EditPerson(Person model, int id, [Size(1024)]IFormFile file)
```

The validation still doesnt take place

Comment: I have also tried with a ValidationAttribute object: